# Need help to format text

Tags: amsmath

Hello i just started to use LaTex a couple of weeks ago and i was wonder if it is possible to make a formatting like this :

```
Ko=1              ..........................................
Kn=?              ..........................................
r=7               ------------Calculation here--------------
n=1               ..........................................
                  ..........................................
```

lets say i want this to be in the righ side (information)

```
\begin{align*}
K_o&=Startværdi \\
K_n&=Slutværdi \\
r&=Rente\\
n&=terminer \\
\end{align*}
```

and then this in the left side (the actual calculation)

```
\subsection{r}
\begin{align*}
K_o&=K_n*(r+1)^n \\
\vspace{5mm} \\
\sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}}&=\sqrt[n]{(1+r} \\
\vspace{5mm} \\
\sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}}-1&=r-1=r(Decimal)*100=r\%
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Use two `minipage`s.

Comment: it seems the link does not work if you do not have a sharelatex-account. Maybe you can post a code snippet here?

Comment: I edited the anwser and pasted the code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place more than one equation on the same line with the `align*` environment.

```
\begin{align*}
K_o & \textup{Startværdi} & K_o & K_n*(r+1)^n \\
K_n & \textup{Slutværdi} & \sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}} & \sqrt[n]{1+r} \\
r & \textup{Rente} & \sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}}-1 & r-1=r(\textup{Decimal})*100=r \\
n & \textup{terminer} \\
\end{align*}
```

[image]

The spacing of the equations on the left part have to be identical to the one on the right, which leave a large space even if not needed.

Another solution would be to use the `aligned` environment.  It as to be inside mathematic

```
\[
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        K_o&=Startværdi \\
        K_n&=Slutværdi \\
        r&=Rente\\
        n&=terminer
    \end{aligned}
    \hspace{5em}    % space between the two part
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        K_o&=K_n*(r+1)^n \\[0.5ex]
        \sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}}&=\sqrt[n]{(1+r} \\[0.5ex]
        \sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}}-1&=r-1=r(Decimal)*100=r\%
\end{aligned}
\]
```

[image]

Then, the spacing of the right part is independant of the one on the left.

Complete code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
K_o &= \textup{Startværdi} & K_o &= K_n*(r+1)^n \\
K_n &= \textup{Slutværdi} & \sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}} &= \sqrt[n]{1+r} \\
r &= \textup{Rente} & \sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}}-1 &= r-1=r(\textup{Decimal})*100=r \\
n &= \textup{terminer} \\
\end{align*}

\[
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        K_o&=Startværdi \\
        K_n&=Slutværdi \\
        r&=Rente\\
        n&=terminer
    \end{aligned}\hspace{5em}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        K_o&=K_n*(r+1)^n \\[0.5ex]
        \sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}}&=\sqrt[n]{(1+r} \\[0.5ex]
        \sqrt[n]{\frac{K_n}{K_o}}-1&=r-1=r(Decimal)*100=r\%
\end{aligned}
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks i think I will go for this solution as it is th emost simple one in the aligned enviroment. can i ask you what the t does in aligned?

Comment: and aswell for the [0.5ex]

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes -- the `[t]` causes the top of the `aligned` block to line up with the top of another component on the same line.  the `[0.5ex]` following a double backslash specifies the amount of extra vertical space to be skipped.